"RV coefficient" relationship to canonical correlation
Canonical correlation addresses the following:

Given matrices $X$ and $Y$, what linear combination of the columns of $X$ best correlates with what linear combination of the columns of $Y$, and what is that correlation?

I have come across an "RV coefficient" that aims to generalize Pearson correlation between univariate random variables to multivariate random variables.
$$
\Sigma_{XY} = \mathbb E\left[XY^T\right]
$$
$$
\text{COVV}\left(X, Y\right) = \text{Trace}\left(\Sigma_{XY} \Sigma_{YX}\right)
$$
$$
\text{VAV}\left(X\right) = \text{Trace}\left(
\Sigma_{XX}^2
\right)
$$
$$
\text{RV}\left(X, Y\right) = \dfrac{
\text{COVV}\left(X, Y\right)
}{
\sqrt{
\text{VAV}\left(X\right)\text{VAV}\left(Y\right)
}
}
$$
This seems like a reasonable-enough vector analogue of the usual Pearson correlation, $\rho\left(X, Y\right) = \dfrac{\text{COV}\left(X, Y\right)}{\sqrt{\text{VAR}\left(X\right)\text{VAR}\left(Y\right)}}$.
But what is this $RV$ coefficient if not just the canonical correlation between $X$ and $Y$, that is, the maximal correlation between linear combinations of $X$ margins with $Y$ margins? (Perhaps some function of the canonical correlation equals the $RV$ coefficient.)
In some code I wrote, this appears not to be the case.
set.seed(2024)

# Does R not have a native matrix trace function?
#
tr <- function(M){
  d <- dim(M)
  n <- d[1]
  m <- d[2]
  s <- rep(NA, n)
  for (i in 1:n){
    s[i] <- M[i, i]
  }
  return(sum(s))
}
a <- matrix(seq(1, 9), 3, 3)

sigma_xy <- function(X, Y){
  P <- scale(X, scale = F) %*% t(scale(Y, scale = F))
  return(cov(P))
}

covv <- function(X, Y){
  m1 <- sigma_xy(X, Y)
  m2 <- sigma_xy(Y, X)
  return(tr(m1 %*% m2))
}

vav <- function(X){
  return(covv(X, X))
}

rv <- function(X, Y){
  return(
    covv(X, Y)/
      sqrt(
        vav(X) * vav(Y)
      )
  )
}

N <- 100
p <- 5
X <- matrix(rnorm(N*p), N, p)
Y <- 7*X + 9 + matrix(rnorm(N, 0, 2), N, p)

rv(X, Y)              # 0.92489
rv(X, Y)^2            # 0.8554215
cancor(X, Y)$cor[p]   # 0.8504828
cancor(X, Y)$cor[p]^2 # 0.723321

The squared $RV$ value is close to the canonical correlation, but they are different enough to leave me uncertain. Is the difference explained by, for instance, the particular estimation procedure, e.g., an $n-1$ denominator in the sample covariance calculations in one place but not the other?

"Does R not have a native matrix trace function?" Nah but you can do tr <- function(A) sum(diag(A)).

The problem in the quote, of finding the best linear combination sounds very much like this problem: Fitting of a sum of vectors $Y \alpha = X \beta + \epsilon$ Possibly it may be of use to gaining some intuition.

In a geometric sense, they appear to be closely related in that they are the same basic thing under two different metrics. Recall this general rule for inner products:
$$\frac{\langle A,B \rangle}{\Vert A\Vert\Vert B\Vert} = \cos(\theta)$$
where $\theta$ is the "angle" between $A$ and $B$.
Now, consider the Frobenius matrix norm for symmetric positive semi-definite real matrices given by $\Vert A\Vert_{\mathcal{F}} = \sqrt{\text{Tr}(A^\top A)}$, and the associated inner product $\langle A,B \rangle_{\mathcal{F}} = \text{Tr}(A^\top B)$. Under this framework, it's clear that the RV coefficient is
$$\frac{\langle \Sigma_{XY},\Sigma_{YX} \rangle_{\mathcal{F}}}{\Vert\Sigma_{XX}\Vert_\mathcal{F}\Vert\Sigma_{YY}\Vert_\mathcal{F}} = \cos(\theta_\mathcal{F}).$$
In CCA/PCA we're implicitly working with the the spectral norm of canonical variables $U$ and $V$, which can be related to the covariance in a number of ways, such as the result of a whitening transform as in this paper. This norm is given by $\Vert A\Vert_2 = \sqrt{\lambda_{\max}(A^\top A)}$.
The first canonical correlation can then be written out as
$$\frac{\langle U,V \rangle_{\mathcal{2}}}{\Vert U\Vert_\mathcal{2}\Vert V\Vert_\mathcal{2}} = \cos(\theta_\mathcal{2}).$$
I would not expect these to be identical since the spectral norm is upper-bounded by the Frobenius norm, and they're operating on different objects so the angle being described is going to be different in some sense.

I need to work through this before I accept it, but +60 for now!

Thanks! It was just the first thing that came to mind; I just went in and edited the answer to clean things up after giving it some more thought. The rv coefficient also seems somewhat related to the cosine similarity metric that's popular in many ML applications.
